# Required permissions cannot be acquired error using Assembly.LoadFrom(String) in winforms

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

I have a winforms application that loads some dll (that I have also written and installed together with the app) at runtime with Assembly.LoadFrom(String). The dll is inside a sub directory of the path where the exe is placed.

Occasionally, the app cannot start in a particular computer and comes out with a exception "Could not load file or assembly 'mydll, Version=1.2.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Failed to grant minimum permission requests. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131417)" and an inner exception "Required permissions cannot be acquired" at "System.Security.SecurityManager.ResolvePolicy(Evidence evidence, PermissionSet reqdPset, PermissionSet optPset, PermissionSet denyPset, PermissionSet& denied, Boolean checkExecutionPermission)".

The code is straight forward:
   `Assembly^ myAssembly = Assembly::LoadFrom(path);`

The dlls need to be loaded at runtime as they are optional.

I have been researching this long but all I find is related to asp.net which does not help me much. I am not using any asp.net.
It only has happened in very, very, few machines to which I have not access neither I do really know the user privileges but the app does not need Admin privileges in any operation and runs with limited user privileges.

Is there a way I can protect the app from this and load the DLL? Obviously, I can handle the exception but, ultimately, I need the dll to be loaded.

Comment: It is the kind of problem your customer's IT staff can only troubleshoot reliably.  They did something unusual when they deployed your app, is is running without full trust.  Like copying the app to an untrusted network share (caspol.exe required) or having copied the files across the internet (right-click file in Explorer and click Unblock).

Comment: @VAndrei This is a winforms app. Do you mean grant access to the programfolder?

Comment: @hansPassant That is also my guess. But was hoping that there could be a way to beat IT!

Answer (score 0):

Can't say if this answer will do you any good or not, but I use an alternate approach to the loading mechanism:

```
String dllFolder = "folder of DLLs";
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), dllFolder));
FileInfo[] fia = di.GetFilesByExactExtension("dll", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
foreach (FileInfo fi in fia)
{
   Byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fi.FullName);
   if (bytes.Length > 0)
   {
       Assembly theDLL = Assembly.Load(bytes);
       if (theDLL != null)
       {
           //...optionally do something more with the instance
       }
   }
}
```

I've had mixed results with the "load it straight from a file via `Load()`" method.

`GetFilesByExactExtension()` is an extension method, btw.

Comment: I thought that in both cases, loading the assembly from the file or from a stream, without overload, the caller is passing the evidence to the assembly. You reckon is a different inner mechanism if I do the file streaming for the CLR? It would definitely help to isolate a IO error...

Answer (score 0):

You could try :

```
Assembly^ myAssembly = Assembly::LoadFrom(Path::Combine(AppDomain::CurrentDomain->BaseDirectory, path))
```

Comment: How is this different to Assembly^ myAssembly = Assembly::LoadFrom(Path) where Path is a full qualified path to the dll in a sub directory of the app folder?